Why is this constraint function so much slower than a similar one and how do I increase the speed in Scipy Optimize?
I have an optimization that has around 22 constraint functions.  I tried to turn that into a single constraint function and the optimizer is taking 10x as long.  Any way to reduce the speed?
The below are the original constraint functions.  I only included 2 but there are like 22 of them, each with hard coded values for the inequality constraint.  The parameters are the values the optimizer is looking for, and the optimizer is looking for like 50 values.  For example, for the first constraint, it basically it says, the first 2 parameter values when summed must not exceed 129:
def MaxConstraint000(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[0:2])
    return (129 - _count)

def MaxConstraint001(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[2:5])
    return (2571 - _count)

_Constraints = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint000}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint001})

To simplify my code and instead of pre-determining the location of parameters I tried something like this, where I supply a key value that pulls in the index locations for the parameter values as well as the constant values [129, 2571, etc...] from a data frame.  DFData has the same number of rows as the number of parameters.  The constraint is identical as the first one, other than I supply a keyValue, which allows me to look up the max value as well as the index locations.
def MaxConstraint(parameters, keyValue):
    _parameters= np.array(parameters)
    _index = np.where(DFData['KeyValues'].values == keyValue)[0] 
    
    _count = np.sum(_parameters[_index])
    _target = DFMaxValues.loc[[keyValue], ['MaxValue']].values[0][0]
    return (_target - _count )

_Constraints = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint, 'args': ('keyValue1', )}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint, 'args': ('keyValue2', )}

This results in 10 times longer execution.  How do I get it down to approximately the same speed as the first one?  I would prefer the second implementation as therefore instead of going into each constraint and changing the MaxValue, I can just update a dictionary or CSV file instead.  Additionally, if the rows of the data get mixed, I don't have hard coded index values.
Thanks!

Full set of constraints:
def MaxConstraint000(parameters):
    _count = np.sum(parameters[0:2])
    return (129 - _count)

def MaxConstraint001(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[2:5])
    return (2571 - _count)

def MaxConstraint002(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[5:8])
    return (3857 - _count)

def MaxConstraint003(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[8:10])
    return (823 - _count)

def MaxConstraint004(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[10:13])
    return (823 - _count)

def MaxConstraint005(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[13:16])
    return (3857 - _count)

def MaxConstraint006(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[16:21])
    return (4714 - _count)

def MaxConstraint007(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[21:25])
    return (3429 - _count)

def MaxConstraint008(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[25:28])
    return (3429 - _count)

def MaxConstraint009(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[28:30])
    return (3429 - _count)

def MaxConstraint010(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[30:33])
    return (2914 - _count)

def MaxConstraint011(parameters):
    _count = np.sum(parameters[33:38])
    return (6000 - _count)

def MaxConstraint012(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[38:43])
    return (6000 - _count)

def MaxConstraint013(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[43:45])
    return (429 - _count)

def MaxConstraint014(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[45:47])
    return (1457 - _count)

def MaxConstraint015(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[47:51])
    return (4286 - _count)

def MaxConstraint016(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[51:53])
    return (2143 - _count)

def MaxConstraint017(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[53:57])
    return (4286 - _count)

def MaxConstraint018(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[57:64])
    return (2143 - _count)

def MaxConstraint019(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[64:67])
    return (2571 - _count)

def MaxConstraint020(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[67:72])
    return (1714 - _count)

def MaxConstraint021(parameters): 
    _count = np.sum(parameters[72:75])
    return (4286 - _count)
    
_Bounds = ((0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000)
           , (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000)
           , (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000)
           , (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000)
           , (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000)
           , (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000)
           , (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000)
           , (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000)
           , (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000)
           , (0, 10000), (0, 10000), (0, 10000))

_Constraints = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint000}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint001}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint002}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint003}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint004}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint005}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint006}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint007}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint008}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint009}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint010}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint011}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint012}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint013}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint014}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint015}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint016}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint017}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint018}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint019}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint020}
                , {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxConstraint021}
               )

############# Solve Optim Problem ############### 
_OptimResultsConstraint = scipy_opt.minimize(ObjectiveFunction
                                             , x0 = [10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000,
                                                   10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000,
                                                   10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000,
                                                   10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000,
                                                   10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000,
                                                   10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000,
                                                   10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000,
                                                   10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000,
                                                   10000, 10000, 10000] # starting guesses
                                             , method = 'trust-constr' # trust-constr, SLSQP
                                             , options = {'maxiter': 1000000000}
                                             , bounds = _Bounds
                                             , constraints = _Constraints) 


Not reproducible. If you actually show your code, I can demonstrate how to combine most (all?) of your constraints into one linear constraint matrix.

ok, let me edit with all the code.  thank you!

do you need the objective function itself or this good enough?

It's still not reproducible, but I'll write a wild-guess answer anyway.

what else do you need?

Your multiple constraints are really just one constraint. The most compact way to represent it is a sparse CSR array:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import LinearConstraint
import scipy.sparse

A = scipy.sparse.csr_array(
    (
        np.ones(75),    # data
        np.arange(75),  # indices
        (
            0, 2, 5, 8, 10, 13, 16, 21, 25, 28,
            30, 33, 38, 43, 45, 47, 51, 53, 57,
            64, 67, 72, 75,
        ),
    ),
)

constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=A,
    ub=(
        129, 2571, 3857, 823, 823, 3857, 4714, 3429, 3429, 3429,
        2914, 6000, 6000, 429, 1457, 4286, 2143, 4286, 2143, 2571,
        1714, 4286,
    ),
)


Ah yes, I just looked into linear constraints.  That is super helpful.

This ended up working wonders.  Didn't realize that I can use a sparse matrix to calculate group by sums, and then feeding that vector into the LinearConstraint was much faster than having a line for each constraint.

you can try using np.bincount in your function,
def MaxConstraint(parameters, keyValue):
    _parameters= np.array(parameters)        
    _count = np.bincount(keyValue,weights=_parameters)
    _target = DFMaxValues.loc[[keyValue], ['MaxValue']].values[0][0]
    return (_target - _count )

_target evaluation can probably be optimized as well, but I may need an example DFMaxValues to come up with an alternative.

Good impulse - but np.bincount() doesn't work on strings.

I guess we can use keyValue=np.unique(keyValue,  return_inverse=True)[1] in case of string keyValue, before inputting it into the function.
